# Show image with jquery in modal using Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

How to show image in modal (#photoss), using jquery which id is called from :

```
 <div class=" top-deal">   
     <a data-toggle="modal" href="#" data-target="#tallModal" class="mask tt" ... photoss="<?php echo $rec->ss;?>" >
```

This my script :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){

              $(".tt").click(function(){

                ....
                 $("#kabkota").html($(this).attr("kabkota"));

                 $('#photoss').html('<img src="'+base_url+'upload/screenshoot/'+ss+'" class="img-responsive">'); // show photo
                 });
               });
          </script>
```

This my modal

```
    <div id="tallModal" class="modal modal-wide fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
     ....
         <h4 id='namaaplikasi'> Nama Aplikasi</h4> </br>
             <div id="photoss">

                </div>
            ...
  </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: So, what's the error? What is not working?

Comment: The image not display, when i try to get image name   $("#photoss").html($(this).attr("photoss")); thats working fine, but when i try display the image which that name in path (upload/screenshoot) with   $('#photoss').html('<img src="'+base_url+'upload/screenshoot/'+ss+'" class="img-responsive">'); that not working..I think i'm wrong with that code..

Comment: you know the right code ?

Comment: @Kurnia please check my code i have first load the image to modal then open it.

Comment: What is the value of `$(this).attr("photoss")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can show image in modal like this.

Use anchor as:

Remove data target attribute and use it as normal anchor as.

```
 <a href="javascript:;"  class="mask tt"  photoss="<?php echo $rec->ss;?>" >
```

Make the script like below:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function(){

              $(document).on("click",".tt",function(){

                var ss  =    $(this).attr("photoss");
                var base_url = "your base url";


                 $('#photoss').html('<img src="'+base_url+'upload/screenshoot/'+ss+'" class="img-responsive">');


                 $("#tallModal").modal("show");

               });
             });   
          </script>
```